# How to hide actionbar and statusbar when user touch on viewpager image and aslo show same when user touches again?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener

//I tried like below code, but it is keep on hide/show calling when i touch every time. please suggest right way to do.

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {




 @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mTouch = true;
                    Log.d("onTouch", "if, true, action down");
                    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
                    // Hide the status bar.
                    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
                    // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
                    // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
                    getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    mPageNoList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   // count++;
                }
                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    Log.d("onTouch", "else, false, action move");
                    // movement: cancel the touch press
                    mTouch = false;
                    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
                    // Hide the status bar.
                    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
                    // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
                    // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
                    getSupportActionBar().show();
                    mPageNoList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //count++;
                }
                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (mTouch) {
                        // touch press complete, show toast
                        Log.d("onTouch", "else if, action up");
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: check here -- http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: using immersive full screen mode working, but i want show back what i hidden when user click again in viewpager. please guide proper way.

Comment: check here on how to 4:52 -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBi8fjv90E4